# sddm presents wrong theme

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, sddm

The problem is that I am presented with a different `sddm` theme when I `logout`.

The default theme works fine when `login`. However, one of the pre-installed themes is used when `logout` the system. Is this a bug or is there a way to configure `sddm` to use a custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/sddm.conf`. In `[Theme]` section add your required theme. For example,

```
[Theme]
Current=theme-name
CursorTheme=cursor-theme-name
```

Comment: This is not the answer since the file has been updated to the respective theme.

Comment: I don't get you. Do you want to use the default theme?

Comment: No, I switched away from it. I made a new one and it works fine when logging in. However, it does not work as suspected when logging out (the default is presented instead of my theme).

Comment: Are you adding your theme to the configuration? Other than that I am out of depth in here.

Comment: Yes. Login == correct theme. Logout && Login = wrong theme.